# How to split time in homogeneous periods

Tags: r, time-series

I have a multivariate time series.
How can I split the global time period into `n` time periods where variables are homogeneous or have similar behaviour?

Comment: Do you know how to determine whether series are homogenous in a given period?

Comment: A possibility may be: a group of series of variables are homogeneous for a given period if the distance between them is minimum. But this is not enough because I can have two very similar series which are very different in 2 periods. The problem is where can I split the time. How can I find the point to cut the time in two parts?

Comment: you need some sort of a distance metric, then somehow find the periods where it's the lowest, maybe pairwise